# What's the etiquette on re-asking questions?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette, asking-questions

If I asked a question a long time ago that has yet to be answered, has stopped getting views, and has all activity has come to a stop, is it ever appropriate to re-ask the question with whatever new info you may have gathered elsewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To provide a similar but slightly different viewpoint to Mark's -- it *can* be OK to re-ask a question, but **only if the original question was asked incorrectly or in a way that confuses answerers and invalidates the existing answers.**

In this case, I think it is OK to flag the question for deletion (or, delete it yourself if it has zero answers) and re-ask with an improved, clearer question.

Comment: Sometimes I see questions that contained some basic flaw because of a typo, like asking about why class inheritance doesn't work, and then showing an example that doesn't do inheritance at all, even though the actual code the OP had did do inheritance. Then you get 10+ answers with plenty of upvotes all saying "You need to inherit from the base class". Is this a valid reason to just flag the question for deletion and re-asking the correct one, or should the OP still edit the question to be correct and just hope people can get over all the answers that are now answering the old question?

Comment: @lasse depends how many broken answers there are; if it's just a few you can leave comments to let them know or mod flags. If it is a lot then the whole question is broken and should be re-asked.

Comment: yes lets ignore that circumstances change over time completely, pretending that it doesn't happen will surely make it true!

Answer (score 6):

It's never appropriate to re-ask a question. If you have new insights that might help a question get answered, you can edit it to add that information, or you can add a bounty to the question, which will bump it to the front page and add it to the featured tab.

More information: [What if I don't get a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty)